# Date Operations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I currently have two variables:

`appointment_date` and `appointment_time` which are in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` and `(h)h:mm` respectively.

The time is 12 hour format but for times before 12PM there is no zero padding as I am grabbing these values from the DOM and this is how it is presented.

I am trying to compare the current date and time with these two values to calculate if the time difference is less than 24 hours which I am able to do with the following hard-coded date objects:

```
var todays_date = new Date(2013, 04, 19, 15, 40, 0);
var appointment_date = new Date(2013, 04, 20, 15, 30, 0);

todays_date = todays_date.getTime();
appointment_date = appointment_date.getTime();

if ((appointment_date - todays_date) >  86400000) { // number of milliseconds in a day
    // proceed 
} else {
    alert('less than 24 hours');
}
```

I can make a date time object from today's date by doing

```
var todays_date = new Date();
```

but I don't know the best way to create a new date object from `appointment_date` and `appointment_time`, bearing in mind that certain times will need to be zero padded as well.

I considered trying to replace the `/` in the date with `,` and the `:` in time with a `,` and joining the two with a `,` in between but I was hoping that were would be a more elegant solution?

Comment: This might be very handy for you: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: What you considered wouldn't work. The Date constructor you're using in your hard coded example has individual number arguments being passed to it; whereas you'd be passing a single argument - a string - that happens to look kind of like the argument list if you were using it properly.

Comment: Side note: Avoid leading zeros on number literals, e.g. don't write `04`, write `4`. Some implementations, in non-strict mode, will treat a number literal starting with a zero [as octal](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1) rather than decimal.

Comment: my rule of thumb with dates is always use epoch times in the code. use formatted dates only for output

Comment: thanks T.J, Anthony and Dave.

Comment: I wouldn't want to use an additional plugin just for this @Ramunas but others might find that helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the `appointment_date` string into its three parts (`split('/')`, for instance), convert those parts to numbers, do the same with the `appointment_time` (`split(':')`), remember to subtract one from the month value (months are zero-based), and pass those numbers into the [`Date` constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2.1).